# building ImageMagick using MinGW64

Tags: imagemagick, mingw-w64

I am trying to compile ImageMagick-7.1.0-1 using MinGW.

The configure script finished peerfectly fine without giving me any errors.

However, running make prints out the following errors:

`` /ld.exe: utilities/magick.o: in function `MagickMain': ``

`` D:\ImageMagick-7.1.0-1\ImageMagick-7.1.0-1/utilities/magick.c:121: undefined reference to `__imp_MagickCoreGenesis' ``

`` ld.exe: D:\ImageMagick-7.1.0-1\ImageMagick-7.1.0-1/utilities/magick.c:122: undefined reference to `__imp_AcquireExceptionInfo' ``

`` ld.exe: D:\ImageMagick-7.1.0-1\ImageMagick-7.1.0-1/utilities/magick.c:123: undefined reference to `__imp_AcquireImageInfo' ``

...

`` ld.exe: D:\ImageMagick-7.1.0-1\ImageMagick-7.1.0-1/MagickWand/stream.c:373: undefined reference to `__imp_DestroyString' ``

`collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

`make[1]: *** [Makefile:8045: utilities/magick.exe] Error 1`

`make[1]: Leaving directory '/d/ImageMagick-7.1.0-1/ImageMagick-7.1.0-1'`

`make: *** [Makefile:6121: all] Error 2`

Considering that it starts with an undefined reference to a function with the word "Magick" in it and the sheer amount of linker errors (i needed to increase the number of scrollback lines to even be able to see the first one), I doubt that it is a missing dependency, but rather a fundamental issue with the way MinGW tries to link files it just compiled itself. Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Comment: I'm able to build this ImageMagick version for Windows with MinGW-w64 for both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows using MSYS2 shell. My `./configure` command contains the following flags `--enable-zero-configuration --with-modules --without-x --with-gslib --without-perl --disable-openmp --enable-hdri --without-wmf`. Can you tell us exactly how you try to build (configure command, etc.)?

Comment: I didn't have --enable-zero-configuration nor --without-x. Adding those flags fixed almost every linker error, except for 5: `NTInitializeWinsock', `__imp_WSAStartup', `__imp_WSAStartup' again, `NTWindowsTerminus' and `__imp_WSACleanup'. I manually had to add -lws2_32 to the LIBS variable in the makefile to make those ones work. Then it ran through to the end with only warnings, most of them being "warning: 'int32' is deprecated". Any ideas why the config script didn't add ws2_32 to the makefile tho?

Comment: I see that I also have `CFLAGS="-fcommon" LDFLAGS="-Wl,--as-needed -lws2_32"` in my `./configure` line. So I had to add that to fix this final link errors.